# Настройка nginx для react и django rest api

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx

Пытаюсь развернуть на сервере проект react.js + django rest + nginx. Как мне настроить nginx, чтобы при обращении пользователя к апи, nginx перенаправлял запрос на django. Сейчас вот такие настройки

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        root /home/django/SocInve/frontend/build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    keepalive_timeout 5;


    location /static/ {
        alias /home/django/SocInve/frontend/build/static/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80/api/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    # необходимо задать для корня расположение index.html
    root /home/django/SocInve/frontend/build; 
    index index.html index.htm;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
        # для корня пытаемся выдать файл, если файл не был найден пытаемся выдать index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location /static/ {
        alias /home/django/SocInve/frontend/build/static/;
    }

    location /api/ {
        # думаю была ошибка, потому что на 80 порту должен сидеть nginx
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/; # если необходимо чтобы api отсекался, то ставим в конце /
        proxy_cookie_path / /api/;
        # проксировать заголовки и схему тоже было бы не плохо
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

По идее должно работать, но могут быть какие то огрехи, их лучше отследить уже непосредственно при запуске nginx. Так же советую проверить порты, на счет них я не уверен, выставил в соответсвии с тем как чаще всего они вставляются. Так же не советую поднимать django на его базовом сервере, лучше для этого использовать gunicorn или что нибудь подобное.

Если будут вопросы спрашивай.